# How can I use Quicktime to record my screen with sound?

Tags: macos, mac, audio, video, quicktime

I know how to do a screen capture with audio. I already installed Soundflower.  I select the output to Soundflower, and I set the setting on my Quicktime.

My question is...how can I also listen to the audio while I record?  If I select soundflower, my headphones don't get any sound.

I want both my headphones AND my quicktime screen capture to have sound.

Comment: Not directly related, but what is the purpose of these recordings? If you plan on sharing them with say Windows users QuickTime is about the worst codec you could choose, and other approaches might make this easier for you (Audacity / Lame to MP3 for example)

Comment: @AthomSfere You can make an mp4 with File > Export > iPad, iPhone. That should play fine for most people.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the included application Soundflowerbed. It will install the **❋** icon in the menubar. From there, activate **Built-in output** (or whatever output your headphones are connected to).